# Solve complex integral: $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos{3\theta}}{5-4\cos\theta}d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to show that the following complex integral is:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos{3\theta}}{5-4\cos\theta}d\theta = \frac{\pi}{12}$$

I have thought about calculating the residues of this function at where the denominator becomes zero but as $\cos\theta$ is always less or equal to 1, I don't know how to apply this method.

Is there any other way for solving this kind of integrals? Please, could you give me any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Remember, $\cos \theta \leq 1$ is only necessarily true when $\theta$ is real. On the complex plane, this does not hold: $\cos(i) = \frac{e^{-1} + e^{1}}{2}$

Comment: Yea, sorry for the typo

Comment: The usual way to these problems is by realizing the intergral as a contour integral which has a countour already chosen for it. So in this case $z + z^{-1} = 2 \cos \theta$

Comment: Must you use complex analysis?  What happens if you render $\cos 3\theta=4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta$ and then $u=\tan(\theta/2)$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi I was just working on that for an answer!  It looks pretty long, I've got a partial fractions to do with four quadratic factors in the denominator.  Plus the usual decomposition will split things into terms that diverge unless you are very careful in grouping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos3\theta}{5 - 4\cos\theta} \ d\theta = \frac{i}{2}\int_{C} \frac{z^3 +z^{-3}}{z(5 - 2(z+z^{-1}))} \ dz $$

Where $C$ is the unit circle and $z = e^{i\theta}$. Simplifying gives

$$\frac{1}{2i}\int_C\frac{z^6+1}{z^3(-2z^2+5z -2)} $$

Then apply the residue theorem.

Comment: Note that the denominator factors as $(2z - 1)(z-2)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=e^{\theta i}$, then $$
I=\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{3 i \theta} d \theta}{5-4 \cos \theta}=\int_{\kappa(0,1)} \frac{z^3 d z}{i z\left[5-2\left(z+z^{-1}\right)\right]}
$$
where $\kappa(0,1)$ is the unit circle with centre O.

Simplifying and factorising yields
$$I=i \int_{\kappa(0,1)} \frac{z^3}{(2 z-1)(z-2)} d z $$The integrand has a simple pole within $\kappa(0,1)$ at $z=\frac{1}{2} $ and the residue is $$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{z^3}{(2 z-1)(z-2)} ,z= \frac{1}{2}\right) & =\lim _{z \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}}\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right) \cdot \frac{z^3}{(2 z-1)(z-2)} \\
& =-\frac{1}{24}
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence $$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\cos 3 \theta d \theta}{5-4 \cos \theta}=Re(I)=Re[2 \pi i \cdot i \cdot(-\frac{1}{24})]=\frac{\pi}{12}
$$
By the way, $$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin{3 \theta} d \theta}{5-4 \cos \theta}=0$$